# Javascript find max subarray with condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how can I make my code's performance a little better.
The challenge is, given an array of random degrees (could be from 0 to 360) and an alpah (degree), I want to find the maximum subarray that is in the value of alpah.

for example: given alpah = 30
and array = [18,36,10,25,300,318,350]

the answer will be 5 because 18,36,10,25,350 are all in the distance of alpah (if you've started checking from 18)

my current code:

```
function countDegrees(alpah, degrees) {
    let maxSoFar = 0;
    let maxEndingHere = 1;
    for(let i = 0; i < degrees.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 1; j < degrees.length; j++) {
            if(getDistanceBetweenDegrees(degrees[i],degrees[j]) <= alpah) {
                maxEndingHere++;
            }
        }
        if(maxSoFar < maxEndingHere) {
            maxSoFar = maxEndingHere;
        }
        maxEndingHere = 1;
    }
    return maxSoFar;
  }
```

currently, it's running with O(N^2), I've heard that there's a way making it O(N), any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only `O(n)` approach I can think of is to use a single loop and check if the current item is within "alpah" of the previously used item:

```js
function countDegrees(maxDiff, degrees) {
  let count = 0;
  let current = degrees[0];
  for (const num of degrees) {
    const naiveDiff = Math.abs(num - current);
    const diff = Math.min(naiveDiff, 360 - naiveDiff);
    if (diff <= maxDiff) {
      count++;
      current = num;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(countDegrees(30, [18, 36, 10, 25, 300, 318, 350]))
```

25 -> 350 is not included because that's a difference of 35, which is more than 30.

If you have to consider different possible branches (that is, not be greedy and take the first number available in range), I don't think O(n) is possible, but I could be wrong.